# How to test Solidity code w/ output as you are writing it?

Tags: testing, methods, ide, solidity

I realize this is a very beginner question so please bear with me. I recently started my first project in Solidity having come from solely using Python. When working with Python I constantly injected print statements to check the output of my work and ensure all was going to plan.

I'm having immense difficulty replicating this same workflow with Solidity. Even on the IDE front, I used PyCharm with Python which has a run command and output window but I can't find anything comparable Solidity. I'm using Sublime Text but that seems to be good for just writing the actual code and I can't find a way to call functions/mappings etc to a window to check output.

Remix has more features than most, but I'd prefer a local development environment. I've been looking for a while now and feel like I'm looking all the wrong places and not sure why the answer is so difficult to find for what seems like a simple issue. Any insight would be amazing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidity has no command line output to display debug values. Which can persuade you to write simpler functions that follow the [single-responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) principle and test their input/output separately.

So instead of writing a long function that does everything and is hard to know what's happening mid-execution

```
function transfer(uint256 _tokenId) external {
    require(msg.sender == ownerOf(_tokenId)
        || isApprovedForAll(ownerOf(_tokenId), msg.sender)
        || msg.sender == getApproved(_tokenId), 'Sender not allowed');

    if (approved != address(0x0)) {
        tokenApprovals[_tokenId] = address(0x0);
        emit Approval(_tokenOwner, address(0x0), _tokenId);
    }

    // ... etc
}
```

you can break the functionality into smaller parts (easier to test separately). And if you need, you can connect them in one function.

```
function transfer(uint256 _tokenId) {
    address tokenOwner = ownerOf(_tokenId);
    address approved = getApproved(_tokenId);

    require(isSenderAllowed(_tokenId, tokenOwner, approved), 'Sender not allowed');

    if (approved != address(0x0)) {
        _removeApproval(_tokenId, tokenOwner);
    }

    // ... etc
}
```

```
function isSenderAllowed(uint256 _tokenId, address _tokenOwner, address _approved) external view returns (bool) {
    return (msg.sender == _tokenOwner
        || isApprovedForAll(_tokenOwner, msg.sender)
        || msg.sender == _approved);
}
```

```
function _removeApproval(uint256 _tokenId, address _tokenOwner) private {
    tokenApprovals[_tokenId] = address(0x0);
    emit Approval(_tokenOwner, address(0x0), _tokenId);
}
```

---

A small workaround for debugging (on a local blockchain such as Ganache or the Remix VM emulator) can be using event logs. You can see them in the transaction return object (if the tx wasn't reverted). However, it's not a good practice, and I'd still recommend writing simplest possible functions instead, so that you don't have to debug that much.

```
contract MyContract {
    event LogString(string memory _value);
    event LogAddress(address _value);

    function foo() external {
        emit LogString("myString");
        emit LogAddress(address(0x123));
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you!  As I'm still working on my initial standalone projects I was really hoping to get the security of being able to constantly check my output, but no luck I guess.  Thanks for info.